# JavaFx 8 TextField in Popup won't focus

Tags: java, javafx-8, japplet

I'm making an applet using JavaFX 8 (via a `JFXPanel`) and was planning on using a `Popup` to display an area with a `TextField` in it.  This works as expected, until the application loses focus.  After that, I'm unable to make the `TextField` regain focus so you can't type in it any more.  I've tried calling `requestFocus()` on the `TextField` but that didn't seem to do anything.  The problem can be seen in the simple example below:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Popup;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FXApplet extends JApplet { 
    protected Scene scene;
    protected Group root;

    @Override
    public final void init() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> initSwing());
    }

    private void initSwing() {
        JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        add(fxPanel);

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            initFX(fxPanel);
            initApplet();
        });
    }

    private void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        root = new Group();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    public void initApplet() {
        Popup popup = new Popup();

        popup.setAutoHide(false);
        popup.getContent().add(new TextField());
        popup.show(scene.getWindow());
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm ... can't reproduce (running in Appletrunner of Eclipse, 8u60ea) - the textfield always has focus (= blinking caret) when applet container in front

Comment: @kleopatra If the applet container loses focus then it doesn't work.  Running on Eclipse I managed to fix it, by adding an on click event listener which requests focus on the JFXPanel, but on a browser, unless the launching tab has focus it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for the info, didn't try in a browser (lazy me ;-) But again: it might be a version problem - the textfield loses focus when the appletcontainer isn't in front (f.i. clicking and typing here) and regains it when moving the container to the front again. In fact, I couldn't make it loose focus nor disappear at all (I see the unfocused textfield on top of this browser window)

Comment: @kleopatra Yeah that's what it does for me.  I feel that since it's on the screen it should be possible to click it and start typing into it no matter what the state of the appletcontainer/browser tab which launched it.  MouseEvents work fine, but can't get Keyboard input to it.  It's possible that it would work in WebStart with the hack to focus the JFXPanel though.